# Xming does not show an xclock window

Tags: windows, putty, xming

I have installed and have connected to a server using Putty.
But when I type "xclock" for testing there is no output.

Answer (score 1):

Check that Xming is accepting connections from the remote host. You can temporarily accept all connections by running Xming with the -ac option.
Also check in your putty options for the session that Connection > SSH > X11 > Enable X11 forwarding is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't get an error message, it means that `xclock` is displaying a window, it could reach your X11 display. So your problem is that you aren't seeing Xming's window.

You have probably configured Xming to display X applications inside an Xming window, so navigate to the Xming window (this “one-window” mode is the default). Alternatively, configure Xming to display X windows on the Windows: start Xming in “multiwindow” mode. See the [Xming manual](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/manual.php) for more information.

It's also possible (but unlikely) that you've done something weird in your configuration file and are overriding the `DISPLAY` variable. It is extremely rare that overriding `DISPLAY` in `.profile` or `.bashrc` or similar files can do anything useful. If you're also logged in inside X on the server's console, and you've overridden `DISPLAY` to be `:0`, then `xclock` is being displayed on the server's GUI.

Comment: xming is working properly when i tested in one server.But am having issues with othr server when i set DISPLAY as :0 and i give command xclock it doesnt show any errors but i am not able to see clock in my machine.But otherwise am getting error "Error: cannot open display: localhost:0"

Comment: Also if i set the DISPLAY as my export DISPLAY=174.16.36.177:0 (system ip )and i try to run firefox it doesnt show any errors but output is not getting displayed.

Comment: Don't set `DISPLAY`. Never set `DISPLAY` over SSH (including PuTTY): if the SSH forwarding is working, the environment variable will be set correctly. If the variable isn't set, you aren't getting X forwarding. Check that you've enabled forwarding in the PuTTY client, that you have `DISPLAY` set on the client side (with Xming, typically to `localhost:0`) and that the server allows X11 forwarding (`X11Forwarding yes` in `sshd_config`).

Comment: I performed steps what you have told.Didnt set the Display in putty .Enabled forwarding . And i logged in to the server and set the DISPLAY to localhost:0 .But no errors,but am not able to see the windows of xclock .As i said on one server it worked well.Also can i know where to look for ssh_config file ?

Comment: @eucap Again: **Do not set `DISPLAY` manually.** Make sure you've set the X display location [in PuTTY](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.62/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-ssh-x11), and that the server accepts X11 forwarding.

Comment: Ok.I have set x display location in Putty and when i tried i got error "
dev2@dev2-Precision-WorkStation-T3500:~$ xclock &
[1] 31644
dev2@dev2-Precision-WorkStation-T3500:~$ Error: Can't open display:"   .Also can you please tell me where to check for ssh_config file ?

Comment: I was able to locate sshd_config file .It is set to yes in that file.Also whne i do echo $DISPLAY on server there is no output

Comment: I compared the server where it is working with one where it is not.I am doing the same steps,but wonder y it works in only i server.When I do echo $DISPLAY on server where it is working i get localhost:10.0 .